# Javascript to PHP - RSA encrypt with modulus and exponent

Tags: javascript, php, encryption, rsa, phpseclib

I have code in javascript https://notepad.pw/codeherejs

```
var c = 'd3bcef1f00424f3261c89323fa8cdfa12bbac400d9fe8bb627e8d27a44bd5d59dce559135d678a8143beb5b8d7056c4e1f89c4e1f152470625b7b41944a97f02da6f605a49a93ec6eb9cbaf2e7ac2b26a354ce69eb265953d2c29e395d6d8c1cdb688978551aa0f7521f290035fad381178da0bea8f9e6adce39020f513133fb';
var f = '10001';
var g = new RSAKey;
    g.setPublic(c, f);
    var result = g.encrypt(password)
```

It working fine. And give me result is`result = 1e2738d762382f82f8412b87e9dd9a18aaa52ea28f6b204bb0f1e0f710a973aaa417e533d39127fd1d8959c553ae53dd83738e4eb6544cb77fd08438afd33594c42ff7e5186bd23908b642188b82b7552140af82f7bd5d768770cd9305573640739be4a70bbc2bd190c5a192685ab88c5a612680005eff2f37944c8e24803ea2`

I conver the code to PHP,  i use phpseclib

```
$fm_modulus = 'd3bcef1f00424f3261c89323fa8cdfa12bbac400d9fe8bb627e8d27a44bd5d59dce559135d678a8143beb5b8d7056c4e1f89c4e1f152470625b7b41944a97f02da6f605a49a93ec6eb9cbaf2e7ac2b26a354ce69eb265953d2c29e395d6d8c1cdb688978551aa0f7521f290035fad381178da0bea8f9e6adce39020f513133fb';

$fm_exponent = '10001';

$rsa = new Crypt_RSA();
$modulus = new Math_BigInteger(base64_decode($fm_modulus), 256);
$exponent = new Math_BigInteger(base64_decode($fm_exponent), 256);

$rsa->loadKey(array('n' => $modulus, 'e' => $exponent));
$pass_ok = $rsa->encrypt($pass);
```

PHP return for me the symbol, i don't know how to convert it to plain text (same result in javascript). I try base64, hash sha256 sha512. All false, please help me

Comment: The encryption returns byte array. What JS shows is a hexadecimal representation of the byte array. Apparently PHP converts it to the string directly.  So you should use something common - Base64 should be good, try to convert the JS array to base64 as well to see the result.

Comment: i try bin2hex, and result i got from php not same Javascript :(

Comment: The result of encryption with a secure cipher *is supposed* to always be different: the results are randomized. You should check by encrypting using one runtime and decrypting using the other runtime. You can try until the world ends to create the same byte array after encryption *even on the same platform*.

Answer (score 0):

`$fm_modulus` and `$fm_exponent` aren't base64-encoded nor are they in base-256. They're hex encoded and that's it. So try this:

```
$rsa = new Crypt_RSA();
$modulus = new Math_BigInteger($fm_modulus, 16);
$exponent = new Math_BigInteger($fm_exponent, 16);
```

I was able to recognize this by the fact that `$fm_exponent` is 10001. 10001 is the hex encoding of [65537](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/65537_(number)), which is a pretty common RSA exponent.

I also suspect the padding mode phpseclib is using may not be correct. You might need to do `$rsa->setEncryptionMode(CRYPT_RSA_ENCRYPTION_NONE);` or `$rsa->setEncryptionMode(CRYPT_RSA_ENCRYPTION_PKCS1);`.

It actually is somewhat hard to know for sure since you didn't post the private key so the result can't be decrypted. You also didn't post the plaintext of what you're trying to encrypt. As Maarten Bodewes said, with good padding modes, the ciphertext will be different every time you try to encrypt the same plaintext but it's possible your JS library isn't using a good padding mode. phpseclib, by default, uses OAEP, which does have randomized output, but "textbook RSA" doesn't use randomized padding (or any padding, really).